# Generics en Scala

Tags: scala

Buenas

Estaba intentando aplicar una función sobre una figura para devolver una nueva figura pero con la posición en x e y cambiadas para esto defino la figura como:

*Para utilizar pattern matching:

```
    case class Circulo(x:Int, y: Int, radio: Double) extends Figura
    case class Rectangulo(x:Int, y: Int, base: Int, altura: Int) 
    extends Figura
    trait Figura[T] {
      val x: Int 
      val y: Int 
    }
```

- La operación para trasladar esta definida en una clase Motor que por ahora no tiene mas funcionalidad que esta:

  ```
  object Motor {

    def trasladar(x: Int, y: Int) = (figura: Figura)  => figura 
    match {
      case Circulo(xPos, yPos, radio) => Circulo(xPos+x, yPos+y, 
      radio)
      case Rectangulo(xPos, yPos, base, altura) => 
      Rectangulo(xPos+x, yPos+y, base, altura)
    }
  }
  ```
- Pareciera funcionar el tema es que cuando corro el test, por ej:

  ```
  "Un Motor" should "trasladar un Circulo" in {

      val trasladar = Motor.trasladar(2,-1)
      val circuloBase = Circulo(1,1,43)
      val circulo = trasladar(circuloBase)

      assert(circulo.x === 3)
      assert(circulo.y === 0)
      assert(circuloBase !== circulo)
      assert(circulo.radio === 43) 
     }
  ```
- No puedo preguntar por el radio del circulo, lo mismo me pasa con otras figuras como rectángulo, cuando pregunto su base, etc. Me dijeron que tenia que usar generics pero todavía no entiendo como usarlos y me tira error de tipos por todos lados, entonces como podría usar generics para arreglar esto? cualquier cambio en el diseño del problema para mejor es bienvenido
  Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que explicar algunas cosas antes de llegar a una posible solución, aunque ya te adelanto que no es tan sencillo como usar *Genéricos*, aunque algo tiene qué ver con *tipos*.

Vamos a ver primero porqué falla, luego una solución siguiendo la *"Programación Orientada a Objetos"* y, finalmente, una solución con *"Clases de Tipos" (typeclasses)* usando *implícitos*.

### Porqué falla

Ante un código scala, la pregunta que hay que hacerse es si el compilador tiene toda la información necesaria para inferir el tipo de todos los objetos. Algunas veces, cuando se presenta una ambigüedad de tipos, el compilador utiliza la regla de usar el tipo más específico (cuando hay *contravarianza*); en otras usa el tipo más general (cuando hay *covarianza*).

En tu caso, la función `Motor.trasladar` tiene una signatura `Figura => Figura` ya que ha de servir igual para `Circulos` que para `Rectangulos`, y `Figura` es el tipo general que cubre a ambos.

Cuando aplicas `Motor.trasladar` a `circuloBase` obtienes entonces una `Figura`, no un `Circulo`, y de ahí que falle. Para poder obtener su atributo `radio` tendrás que convertirlo primero a `Circulo`:

```
val trasladar = Motor.trasladar(2,-1)
val circuloBase = Circulo(1,1,43)
val circulo = trasladar(circuloBase).asInstanceOf[Circulo]
```

No es una buena solución ya que la "conversión" de tipos se realizar en ejecución, con el consiguiente riesgo de que se produzcan errores. Tenemos que buscar una solución mejor.

### Orientación de Objetos

La forma más habitual de resolver el problema sería refactorizar las clases para que contuvieran el método:

```
trait Figura {
  val x: Int
  val y: Int
  def trasladar(x: Int, y: Int): Figura
}

case class Circulo(x: Int, y: Int, radio: Double) extends Figura {
  def trasladar(x: Int, y: Int) = this.copy(x = this.x + x, y = this.y + y)
}

case class Rectangulo(x: Int, y: Int, base: Int, altura: Int) extends Figura {
  def trasladar(x: Int, y: Int) = this.copy(x = this.x + x, y = this.y + y)
}
```

Para usarlo:

```
val circuloBase = Circulo(1, 1, 43)
val circulo = circuloBase.trasladar(2, -1)
```

Supongo que el incoveniente es que quieres crear más operaciones sobre estos objetos, pero sin modificar el modelo. Digamos que tienes en unos fuentes que no quieres tocar. Entonces esta solución no es factible. Veamos otra cosa...

### Tipos genéricos

Veamos si podemos usar tipos genéricos:

```
def trasladar[T <: Figura](x: Int, y: Int) = (figura: T)  =>
  figura match {
    case Circulo(xPos, yPos, radio) => Circulo(xPos+x, yPos+y, radio)
    case Rectangulo(xPos, yPos, base, altura) => Rectangulo(xPos+x, yPos+y, base, altura)
  }
```

En esta parametrización de tipos indicamos que el tipo `T` ha de ser subtipo de `Figura`, indicado por `T <: Figura`. La transformación `trasladar` convierte un objeto de tipo `T` en otro de tipo `T`.

Podemos pensar que va a ir bien, ya que cuando se aplique a un objeto `Circulo`, `T` será igual a `Circulo` y entonces devolverá un `Circulo`, y lo mismo cuando se aplique a `Rectangulo`.

El problema es que el compilador no sabe a qué se aplicará la función, por lo que no puede relacionar `T` con algunos de los subtipos de `Figura`.

Es posible que en nuevas implementaciones de scala (eg: con [dotty](https://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/dotty)) se tengan tipos compuestos que pudieran resolver este problema. Pero hoy en día se tiene claro que la mejor forma es usando *typeclasses* con implícitos, y cada vez serán más presente en las librerías de scala.

### Clases de tipos (typeclass)

Las **typeclass** no tienen ninguna relación con las *"Clases de Objetos"* que se ve en programación orientada a objeto. Provienen de la [Teoría de Categorías](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teor%C3%ADa_de_categor%C3%ADas) que tan bién han sabido implementar en haskell y que se extiende ya a otros lenguajes funcionales como scala.

Digamos que queremos definir una serie de operaciones para luego implementarlas sobre distintos tipos de datos. El conjunto de estas operaciones sería nuestra *"clase de tipos"* (*typeclass*):

```
trait Transform[T <: Figura] {
  def trasladar(x: Int, y: Int): T => T
}
```

Sólo tenemos una operación, pero podríamos definir todas las que necesitemos, o incluso añadir más *typeclasses* con otros conjuntos de operaciones.

Definimos las transformaciones para cada uno de los tipos que tenemos (lo que se denomina *"crear instancias de la typeclass"*):

```
object TransformCirculos extends Transform[Circulo] {
  def trasladar(x: Int, y: Int) =
    circulo => circulo.copy(x = x + circulo.x, y = y + circulo.y)
}

object TransformRectangulos extends Transform[Rectangulo] {
  def trasladar(x: Int, y: Int) =
    rect => rect.copy(x = x + rect.x, y = y + rect.y)
}
```

Quedando la función trasladar de este modo:

```
def trasladar[T <: Figura](x: Int, y: Int)(figura: T)(tr: Transform[T]) =
  tr.trasladar(x, y)(figura)
```

El incoveniente es que cada vez que hagamos un `trasladar` tendremos que pasar de modo explícito el objeto `Transform` correspondiente:

```
val trasladar = Motor.trasladar(2,-1)(_: Circulo)(Motor.TransformCirculos)
```

Podemos evitarlo si hacemos los objetos *Transform* implícitos, así como el argumento de la función:

```
implicit object TransformCirculos extends Transform[Circulo] {
  def trasladar(x: Int, y: Int) =
    circulo => circulo.copy(x = x + circulo.x, y = y + circulo.y)
}

implicit object TransformRectangulos extends Transform[Rectangulo] {
  def trasladar(x: Int, y: Int) =
    rect => rect.copy(x = x + rect.x, y = y + rect.y)
}

def trasladar[T <: Figura](x: Int, y: Int)(figura: T)(implicit tr: Transform[T]) =
  tr.trasladar(x, y)(figura)
```

De este modo, no tendríamos que explicitar el objeto transformación siempre que la función `trasladar` lo encuentre dentro de su entorno:

```
val trasladar = Motor.trasladar(2,-1)(_: Circulo)
```

Aún así, no podríamos hacer esto:

```
val trasladar = Motor.trasladar(2,-1)
```

ya que el compilador no tiene la información necesaria sobre los tipos de datos a los que se va a aplicar. En cambio, sí es posible la alternativa de explicitar el tipo de dato:

```
val trasladar = Motor.trasladar[Circulo](2,-1) _
```

Obsevar el subrayado `_` que hay al final indicando al compilador que queremos operar con la función y no dé error por tomarlo como método.

### Final

Finalmente, pongo el código completo para que quede más claro:

```
trait Figura {
  val x: Int
  val y: Int
}

case class Circulo(x: Int, y: Int, radio: Double) extends Figura
case class Rectangulo(x: Int, y: Int, base: Int, altura: Int) extends Figura

object FiguraMain extends App {

  object Motor {

    trait Transform[T <: Figura] {
      def trasladar(x: Int, y: Int): T => T
    }

    implicit object TransformCirculos extends Transform[Circulo] {
      def trasladar(x: Int, y: Int) =
        circulo => circulo.copy(x = x + circulo.x, y = y + circulo.y)
    }

    implicit object TransformRectangulos extends Transform[Rectangulo] {
      def trasladar(x: Int, y: Int) =
        rect => rect.copy(x = x + rect.x, y = y + rect.y)
    }

    def trasladar[T <: Figura](x: Int, y: Int)(figura: T)(implicit tr: Transform[T]) =
      tr.trasladar(x, y)(figura)

  }

  def main = {

    val trasladar = Motor.trasladar[Circulo](2, -1) _
    val circuloBase = Circulo(1, 1, 43)
    val circulo = trasladar(circuloBase)

    assert(circulo.x == 3)
    assert(circulo.y == 0)
    assert(circuloBase != circulo)
    assert(circulo.radio == 43)
  }
}
```